# How work translate=True in layout.label ? (Python Ui question)

Tags: python, scripting, interface

I'm trying translate = True, in a label, but I see that no translation is done when I change the languages in the preferences, now I don't understand how this option works and if it can work, I'd like to understand if it is possible to translate automatically.

```
layout.label(text='My Text', translate=True)
```

The output on the interface is always "My text" tested in all languages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no automatic translation, you will have to create a dictionary with the translations that is registered/unregistered through `bpy.app.translations.register()` and
`bpy.app.translations.unregister()`. The *Manage UI Translations* add-on can help you generate the tuples from which the dictionary is generated.

More information can be found in the [manual](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.app.translations.html) and the [wiki](https://wiki.blender.org/wiki/Process/Translate_Blender#Translating_non-official_addons).

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I wanted to understand how to handle this, I will follow your advice